# How I deal with multiple actions calling different functions in redux saga?

Tags: javascript, redux, generator, yield, redux-saga

Here an example which is going to be easier to understand.

```js
function* a() {
 yield takeEvery(action.LOGIN_SUCCESS, b)
}

function* b() {
  yield takeEvery(action.FETCH_SUCCESS, c)
}

function* c() {
  yield console.log('action from function a')

}

function* d() {
yield takeEvery(action.FETCH_SUCCESS, e)

}

function* e() {
  yield console.log('action from function d')
}



yield all([
  fork(a),
  fork(d),
])
```

If LOGIN_SUCCESS happens then function b starts waiting for FETCH_SUCCESS.
At the same time, function d is waiting for FETCH_SUCCESS.

The question is: how can I stop function d from running after the takeEvery in function a takes the LOGIN_SUCCESS and then FETCH_SUCCESS action?

In this case I want only function c to be called. Instead, what happens is that both function c and function e are called because FETCH_SUCCESS happens.

The idea is that I would like to have something in redux saga which remembers the previous action taken by the previous generator so that I can distinguish two different paths:

`1) LOGIN_SUCCESS -> FETCH_SUCCESS -> function c`

`2) FETCH_SUCCESS -> function e`

Hope I have been clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying saga `d` like so:

```
function* d() {
  const task = yield takeEvery(action.FETCH_SUCCESS, e)
  yield take(action.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
  yield cancel(task)
}
```

This will kill the takeEvery in saga `d` once `LOGIN_SUCCESS` is dispatched.

Since you are using `takeEvery` for `LOGIN_SUCCESS` I assume it is something that can happen multiple times. In that case you will probably want to run another saga `d` on logout.

Comment: With this solution you wouldn't cover this case: if LOGIN_SUCCESS happens function b is called, then when FETCH_SUCCESS happens both function c and e are called again, is that right?